# Insert с выборкой значенией из другой таблицы и изменением значения

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть вот такой запрос

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`product_id`,`customer_group_id`,`priority`,`price`,`date_start`,`date_end`)
           VALUES 
           ((SELECT `product_id` FROM `table2` 
           WHERE 
           product_code_id = '1223232ssdsad34'),'1','0','34332','2018-04-22','2018-04-26');
```

Как можно еще для `price`, получить текущее его значение из таблицы `table2`, вычесть 10% и вставить в `table1`?

Comment: А вы все данные получайте как будто из таблицы (в запросе можно получать константы): `insert into table1(...) select product_id, 1,0, ..., price, ... from table2`

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (product_id,customer_group_id,priority,price,date_start,date_end)
(SELECT product_id ,'1','0',price * 0.9,'2018-04-22','2018-04-26'
FROM table2
WHERE product_code_id = '1223232ssdsad34');
```